# Node Js request post not sending the form POST data to LAMP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, http-post

This is sample code which is not posting the form data to php server, null data is recived

The below code will send the complete html data to php where in php i'm converting to doc format for the html and start downloading automatically, but currently node js is not sending me the post value to php server to the url http://domain.com/index.php

```
exports.download = function (req, res) {
    var doc = "<html><body>content</body></html>";
    var doctype = req.body.doctype; 
    var fs = require('fs');
    var request = require('request');
    var request_url_docx = 'http://domain.com/index.php';
    var r = request.post(request_url_docx);
    var time_stamp = Date.now()/1000;
    var form = r.form();
    form.append('filename', doctype+"_"+time_stamp);
    form.append('filedata',doc);
    r.pipe(res);
}
```

Comment: If your request is being sent to the LAMP server and the lamp server is responding with null, your problem probably lies in the PHP code right? Also, you have to explain what exactly you are trying to do with the code.

Comment: No in php there is no issue i have just echo the data which is been receiving like this print_r($_REQUEST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i Found a middle where you can use simple post to action to url to php file when event occur where you can process the document section for the HTML which is available in the phpdoc module you can generate the HTML to DOC in Node Js

This works for me.